Rearrange sum of sum with factors into a double sum with replace
I'd like to re-arrange a complex expression, a simplified form can be expressed as:
i, j, N = symbols("i j N", integers=True, finite=True, nonnegative=True)
a, b, c, d, e = symbols("a b c d e", cls=IndexedBase)

expr = (Sum(a[i] * Sum(b[i] * d[j], (j, 1, N)) * c[i], (i, 1, N)) 
        + Sum(a[i] * Sum(b[i] * e[j], (j, 1, N)) * c[i], (i, 1, N)))
expr


Ideally, I'd like to convert to something like the following:

I've not used replace much before but it seemed like it might be useful for this type of manipulation. Unfortunately, my attempt doesn't properly capture the dummy variables:
ws1, ws2, ws3, wd1, wd2, wl1 = symbols("ws1 ws2 ws3 wd1 wd2 wl1", cls=Wild)

expr.replace(
    Sum(ws1 * Sum(ws3, (wd1, 1, wl1)), (wd2, 1, wl1)) * ws2,  
    Sum(ws1 * ws2 * ws3, (wd1, 1, wl1), (wd2, 1, wl1))
)


Wondering if anyone could offer any suggestions?

I found a way to do it with replace by using a filter / func combination. It seems to work for my simple example posted above but will need further testing. I did it as follows:
def sum_denest(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, Sum):
        if (mul := expr.args[0]).is_Mul:
            summand_sum = [a for a in mul.args if isinstance(a, Sum)]
            summand_no_sum = [a for a in mul.args if not isinstance(a, Sum)]
            if summand_sum and summand_no_sum:
                limits = list(expr.args[1:])
                for s in summand_sum:
                    limits.extend(s.args[1:])
                    summand_no_sum.extend(
                        s.args[0].args if isinstance(s.args[0], Mul) else a.args[0]
                    )
                return Sum(Mul(*summand_no_sum), *limits)
    return expr


expr.replace(lambda expr: sum_denest(expr) != expr, sum_denest)


